# PLSQL Daily record of changes on table, then select from day

Tags: oracle, plsql, merge

Oracle PL SQL question: One table should be archived day by day. Table counts about 50.000 records. But only few records during a day are changed. Second table (destination/history table) has one additional field - import_date. Two days = 100.000 records. Should be 50.000 + feq records with informations about changes during a day.

I need one simple solution to copy data from source table to destination like a "LOG" - only changes are copied/registered. But I should have possibility to check dataset of source table from given day.

Is there such mechanism like MERGE or something like that?

Comment: Have you tried triggers for copying the changed data to separate table?

Comment: Which *exact* version of Oracle are you using? 11.2.0.4 or higher?

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure? Also: please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question, some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: How about [Don't reinvent database features but use native functionality instead](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/139014/15012) ?

Comment: Do you have the partition option licensed?  With partitioning you may not even need to archive the data - just keep each day in a separate partition and Oracle will treat each day like a separate table.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd have a day_table and a master_table. All records are loaded from the day_table into master and only master is manipulated with the day table used to store the raw data.

You could add a new column to master such as a date_modified and have the app update this field when a record changes, or a flag used to indicate it's changed.

Another way to do this is to have an active/latest flag. Instead of changing the record it is duplicated with a flag set to indicate this is a better/old record. This might be easier for comparison

```
e.g. select * from master_table where record = 'abcd'
```

This would show 2 rows - the original loaded at 1pm and the modified active one changed at 2pm.

There's no need to have another table, you could base a view on this flag then

```
e.g. CHANGED_RECORDS_VIEW = select * from master_table where flag = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

Once i faced a similar issue. And please find the solution below.

### Tables we had :

1. Master table always has records it and keeps adding up.
2. One backup table to store all the master records on daily basis.

### Solution:

From morning to evening records are inserted and updated into the master table. The concept of finding out the new records was the timestamp. Whenever a new record is inserted/updated then corresponding timestamp is added and kept.

At night, we had created a job schedule to run a procedure (Create_Job-> please check oracle documentations for further learning) which runs exactly at 10:00 pm to bulk collect all the records available in master table based on today's date and insert into the backup table.

This scenrio which i have explained to you will help you. Please check out the concept of Job scheduling which will help you. Thank you .